# Make responsive navbar in bootstrap?

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

Is there any way to make responsive without collapse? I don't want to use collapse, because It hides all menu in a button. I want to keep some lists that aren't affected by screen solution.

Sorry for my explanation. What I want is hide some lists in dropdown, but keep some. Please visit [www.plus.google.com](https://plus.google.com) for example.

Comment: What version? In 2 you can just `not` use the collapse classes, however I'm not sure in 3RC1 I noticed it does it regardless.

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is. Lets take basisc navbar example:

```
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
      <div class="navbar-inner">
        <div class="container">
          <button data-target=".nav-collapse" data-toggle="collapse" class="btn btn-navbar" type="button">
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <a href="#" class="brand">Project name</a>
          <div class="nav-collapse collapse">
            <ul class="nav">
              <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
              <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
              <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

And modify it by deleting `<button ... ./>` you dont need it. Another thing you should do is remove `nav-collapse collapse` classes. Finally:

```
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
      <div class="navbar-inner">
        <div class="container">

          <a href="#" class="brand">Project name</a>
            <ul class="nav">
              <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
              <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
              <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: I'm trying to work though creating a demo of this answer but I'm not seeing the result that I think the OP is after: http://jsfiddle.net/sperske/e9fBm/